# paramiko multiple commands as argument

Tags: python, paramiko

I am working on automation. here i am facing challenge to execute n number of commands on Linux device concurrently or sequentially. Now i am using the below method but i have create static config for each command instead of that is there any way to use list of commands. may be the number of commands will change in different scenario

```
ssh    = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.connect(host, username=user,password=passwd )
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd1)
output1 = stdout.read()
data1 = str(output1)
displaymessage1 = data1
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd2)
output1 = stdout.read()
data1 = str(output1)
#print data1
displaymessage2 = data1
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd3)
output1 = stdout.read()
data1 = str(output1)
#print data1
displaymessage3 = data1
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd4)
output1 = stdout.read()
data1 = str(output1)
#print data1
displaymessage4 = data1
stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd5)
output1 = stdout.read()
data1 = str(output1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider to refactor the code into a function that accepts command to run and keep the command in a list. Something like

```
def run_command(cmd):
    ssh    = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, username=user,password=passwd )
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    output = stdout.read()
    return str(output)

commands_list = [cmd1, cmd2, cmd3, cmd4]

# run each command in the list and keep the output in data
data = [run_command(cmd) for cmd in commands_list]
```

Comment: In this case how we can handle exception for connection failed or time out

Comment: any idea about adding paramiko exception

Comment: it depends on what you want to do in the event of exception. To catch the exception, you can add a try-except in the function